# How to continue the loss/step information when finetune an model

Tags: tensorflow

I use the tf.train.Supervisor to finetune a basic model in tensorflow. The following is the related code.

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(
     logdir=args.checkpoint_dir,
     save_summaries_secs=args.summary_interval,
     save_model_secs=args.checkpoint_interval,
     init_fn=load_initial_weights_insess) 

#using moving average to update loss and psnr
update_ma = ema.apply([loss, psnr])

def load_initial_weights_insess(sess):
    log.info("------------------------------------------")
    if len(initial_ckpt) <= 0:
        return
    log.info('Prepare to load initial weights from {}'.format(initial_ckpt))
    log.info("Variables to load initial weights are:")
    for v in initial_variables:
        log.info("----{}".format(v.name))
    initial_saver.restore(sess, initial_ckpt)
    log.info("Finished load initial weights")
```

The code can work well. But it can’t continue the loss/step information in the basic model.That’s to say, it always initiate the loss/step information, rather than continue them in the finetuneing processing. From my perspective, the initial value of loss(0)  may lead to a bad optimization direction.

```
#Training log for the basic model, the following log is from the end step:
Step 88689 | loss = 0.0551 | psnr = 30.8 dB 

#Finetune log:
Step 0   | loss = 0.0    | psnr = 0.0 dB 
Step 52  | loss = 0.0012 | psnr = 4.1 dB 
Step 103 | loss = 0.0029 | psnr = 7.2 dB
```

So my question is how to continue the loss/step information when finetune a model.Great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize the [`tf.train.Supervisor()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Supervisor#__init__) you can pass it the `global_step` argument. You can also make sure the `global_step` variable is added to the SAVEABLE_OBJECTS collection and thus saved/restored with the model. This is how the objects to save and restore are collected in the [TensorFlow source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bdab2d9672454df7051f250a1ca12f59ab12dccc/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#L1423):

```py
return (ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope) +
        ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS, scope))
```

The problem with the loss is somewhat different, because when you start the finetuning, it has no value. So you can do two approaches. One is to again, add it to the SAVEABLE_OBJECTS collection and save/restore it with the model. The other one is to use the `zero_debias` argument of [`tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage#__init__) where you set it up (not visible in your code.) That will make sure the initial value of zero for loss will not bias the moving average downwards.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I can get the right loss by using zero_debias. But I still can't continue the global_step.

Comment: Updated answer with more accurate info and source reference to set the proper collection on global_step so that is is saved and restored

Answer (score 0):

In the pretraining, initialize a "global_step" variable and use it with the preliminary optimizer before *saving*. tf.train.Superviser can then be passed the global_step that is *restored* from the preliminary training session through its **init**, check the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Supervisor)